# Laravel Count with where inside blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the total comments the user have..

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $setting = Setting::findOrFail(1);

    $comments = Comment::where('published', '=', '1')->get();

    $users = User::all();

    return view('page.index', compact('setting', 'comments', 'users'));
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)

{{ count($users->where('user_id', '=', $comment->user_id)) }}

@endforeach
```

The problem is that it only returns 0 and i have 2 comments there.. even using the user id to instead of "$comment->user_id" it doesnt work. still display 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$users` is a collection, not a query. Treat it as such:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)

    {{ $users->where('user_id', $comment->user_id)->count() }}

@endforeach
```

The collection's [`where`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-where) method does [not take an operator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L145).

---

From the wording in your question it seems you actually want it the other way around:

```
$comments = Comment::wherePublished(1)->get()->groupBy('user_id');
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

    {{ $comments->has($user->id) ? count($comments[$user->id]) : 0 }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i've actually tried it out, but i added , '=' in the where, it was also giving me 0.. lol Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to answer your question and `Joseph` already showed you the problem but you may also do it differently. You can group comments using `Collection::groupBy`, for example:

```
$comments = Comment::all()->groupBy('user_id');
```

Then in your `view` you may try this:

```
@foreach($comments as $user => $userComments)
     // count($userComments)
     // Or
     @foreach($userComments as $comment)
      // {{ $comment->title }}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

In the first loop (`@foreach($comments as $user => $userComments)`), the `$user` is the `user_id` and it's value would be all comments (an array) by this user but in group.

Comment: Plus 1. Way more efficient. I was just trying to stay as close to the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks mate, yes, you did the right thing because `OP` was on wrong direction but you made him clear, he learned something :-)